# Warning: React does not recognize the `textAlign` prop on a DOM element

Tags: material-ui, styled-components

> ...  If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `textalign` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.

I am getting this warning when trying to use `styled-system` in combination with `material-ui`.

The code:

```
const textAlign = style({
  // React prop name
  prop: "textAlign",
  // The corresponding CSS property (defaults to prop argument)
  cssProperty: "textAlign",
  // key for theme values
  key: "textAlign",
  // accessor function for transforming the value
  transformValue: (n: string) => {
    return `${n} !important;`
  }
  // add a fallback scale object or array, if theme is not present
})

export const UiTableCell = uiTableCell`
   ${fontSize};
   ${textAlign};
   border-bottom: none !important;
   padding-top: 8px !important;
   padding-right: 20px !important; 
   padding-left: 20px !important; 
   padding-bottom: 8px !important;
   white-space: nowrap;
   position: relative;
   color: ${(props) => (props.color ? props.color : theme.colors.text)} !important;
`
```

and its usage in a component:

```
<UiTableCell textAlign="right" fontSize={[2]}>
  <Text ml={[4]}>{stuff}</Text>
</UiTableCell>
```

It does not keep the app from working but the warning is polluting the debugging console...

Comment: Would you update the question with a reproducible link? codesandbox maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that UiTableCell component is passing down all properties which it doesn't recognize. As long as it renders "td" tag this results in a DOM node like:

```
<td textAlign="right"></td>
```

where "textAlign" is not parsed as valid HTML attribute.

Instead of styling UiTableCell directly you should create a wrapper component with all custom styles (passed as props) you need and put UiTableCell content inside of it.

Check full demo based on your example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/n91k87r26p